# Select/Deselect a group of checkboxes on a webpage with Selenium in VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, ms-access, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Below is a part of a frame of a webpage with 6 checkboxes. I'm trying to create a reusable script in VBA that selects or deselects all checkboxes within this table element.

Here there are multiple checkboxes in one table cell, so my attempt to do it with a table element didn't work.

I think that a procedure based on "For each  in  could do the trick, but unfortunately I cannot  get it to work. On the other hand I may also go through all elements having "//input[@type='checkbox']" on the page and then check if the parent element matches "/p[@id='p_status']/table/tbody/tr/td". But also here, selecting the element is easy, but validating the parent element keeps failing. Perhaps I'm missing an important option here.

Maybe there is a possibility to create the code, but I really appreciate some help here.

```
<p id="p_status" style="">
<table width="50%" align="center">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td nowrap="">
            <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="X"><b>Dr</b><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="W" checked=""><b>Pe</b><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="R"><b>Re</b>
        </td>
        <td nowrap="" width="50%">
            <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="U"><b>UI</b><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="A"><b>Au</b><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="Q"><b>SA</b>                        
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
</p>
```

Art.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select / deselect  all check box in one go you can use below code:

```
Set checkboxes= driver.FindElementsByXPath("//p[@id='p_status']//input[@type='checkbox']")
For Each checkbox In checkboxes
    checkbox.Click
Next
```

It will select all deselected checkbox and vice versa.

However, if you want to **create a reusable function** to select /deselect any one checkbox at a given time. You can create a function like this:

```
Sub Check_checkboxLogo(driver As WebDriver, lbl as String)
    set xpath_Checkbox = "//p[@id='p_status']//b[text()='"& lbl &"']//preceding-sibling::input[@type='checkbox']"
    driver.FindElementByXPath(xpath_Checkbox).Click
End Sub
```

**Now you can call** above function like `Check_checkboxLogo(driver, "Dr")` or `Check_checkboxLogo(driver, "Pe")` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Rahul! Somehow some parts of my question were omitted at **For each Webelement in Webelements **, but I expected the solution should be found here.

My reusable solution is more generic, but does the same:

```
Public Function AllCkBoxes(strXP As String, _
                           Optional blnSelect As Boolean = False, _
                           Optional lngTimeOut As Long = 500)
    
    'This function deselects (blnSelect=False) or selects (blnSelect=True) all child checkboxes of a webelement

    On Error GoTo Err_Proc
    
    Dim lngResult As Long
    Dim wEle As WebElement
    Dim wEles As WebElements
    Dim strXpType As String

    With driver
        strXpType = "//preceding-sibling::input[@type='checkbox']"
        lngResult = .FindElementsByXPath(XPath:=strXP & strXpType).Count
        If lngResult > 0 Then
            Set wEles = .FindElementsByXPath(XPath:=strXP & strXpType, timeout:=lngTimeOut)
            For Each wEle In wEles
                If wEle.IsSelected <> blnSelect Then
                    wEle.Click
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End With

Exit_Proc:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wEle = Nothing
    Set wEles = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_Proc:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error: " & CStr(Err.Number) & vbCrLf & _
                   "Desc: " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                   "Source: " & Err.Source & vbCrLf & _
                   "Library: " & Application.CurrentProject.Name & vbCrLf & _
                   "Module: Mod_RA" & vbCrLf & _
                   "Function: AllCkBoxes" & vbCrLf, _
                   vbCritical, "Error"
    End Select
    Resume Exit_Proc
    Resume
End Function
```

Again, thanks!

Art.